# Box 56 - PPIP insurable earnings (RL

Tags: canada, income-tax, quebec

Another question about Quebec tax return: I have field: Box 56 - PPIP insurable earnings (RL-1 Box I) in T4 Slip Income (RL-1) and in T4 box 56 is empty, but in RL-1 Box I has value equals to all salary. Which amount should I enter to this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, just found the following [info](http://support.drtax.ca/ufile/kb/web/source/webpages/kpa390-20080115161223sc.htm): If the RL-1 document is different from the T4 document for Box 56, then enter the amount from the RL-1 document.